# How to convert animation and audio into a video in windows phone 8 and windows 8 metro

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-8, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

I am developing an application which has a animation in it and while the animation is playing the user can sing the song which he likes but then he can then listen to the animation with audio he sang then he can even share that on facebook or other networking sites. The things I have achieved is that a can play it on device by playing animation and audio but I am not able share it to the facebook as it is not a video. is there any way so that I can convert it to video and share. I have searched a lot about it but did not found anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can encode and do something like similar with this code;

```
MediaItem src = new MediaItem(sourceAudioFile); 
            switch (outputAudioType) 
            { 
                case OutputAudioType.MP4: 
                    src.OutputFormat = new MP4OutputFormat(); 
                    src.OutputFormat.AudioProfile = new AacAudioProfile(); 
                    src.OutputFormat.AudioProfile.Codec = AudioCodec.AAC; 
                    src.OutputFormat.AudioProfile.BitsPerSample = 24; 
                    break; 
                case OutputAudioType.WMA: 
                    src.OutputFormat = new WindowsMediaOutputFormat(); 
                    src.OutputFormat.AudioProfile = new WmaAudioProfile(); 
                    src.OutputFormat.AudioProfile.Bitrate = new VariableConstrainedBitrate(128, 192); 
                    src.OutputFormat.AudioProfile.Codec = AudioCodec.WmaProfessional; 
                    src.OutputFormat.AudioProfile.BitsPerSample = 24; 
                    break; 
            } 

            TimeSpan spanStart = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(startpoint); 
            src.Sources[0].Clips[0].StartTime = spanStart; 
            TimeSpan spanEnd = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(endpoint); 
            src.Sources[0].Clips[0].EndTime = spanEnd; 

            job.MediaItems.Add(src); 
            job.OutputDirectory = outputDirectory; 
            job.Encode(); 

            return job.MediaItems[0].ActualOutputFileFullPath; 
        } 
    }
```